# Check if an instance in AWS have absolutely no tags using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm using python boto3 to query and update tags from AWS instances. I'm trying to handle a condition where there are 'NO' tags present on an instance. I figured that the tags are actually list of dictionaries in a boto3 ec2 query response, however none of the methods for checking a non-existent 'list' is working. I have tried following options (i['Tags'] is list of tags)

```
if i['Tags']:
if not i['Tags']:
if len(i['Tags']) != 0:
```

Since no tags are present on the instance, all the above conditions fail with the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tag-automation.py", line 106, in <module>
    read_instance_tags()
  File "./tag-automation.py", line 81, in read_instance_tags
    if not i['Tags']:
KeyError: 'Tags'
```

Any pointers to fix this would be greatly helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no tags, then there would not be a `Tags` entry in the dictionary.

Therefore, use:

```
if 'Tags' not in i:
```